# Error when connecting an Access query to an excel sheet -expression in query prevents connection being made

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, query, microsoft-access-2010

I have an Excel sheet which is linked to a query in my Access database (both 2010 version). It works really well and I decided that I wanted to have the same Excel sheet but to only contain data for an individual site.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

So, I copied the query, renamed it and added the following criteria under the site field: [Forms]![BASIL-3 CRF Tracking]![Selectsite] ... the query works fine it only returns results from the site selected from a pull-down box on a form in the db.

However, when I go to Excel, that new query isn't listed to connect to. If I delete the above expression in the query then it re-appears in the list. If I make the connection to the query then add the expression in and then refresh the connection I get an error (see image).